# Endpoint name changes are not reflected when service is updated

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, azure-service-fabric

I am working on a service fabric project and it has two services stateless and state-full.

1. Stateless Service

   - It contains two endpoints called "CreateOrUpdateStudent" and "GetStudent".
2. State-full Service

   - It contains logic implementation of "CreateOrUpdateStudent" and "GetStudent"
     I have deployed service to cluster and able to it below endpoints and get a response.
3. http://..../CreateOrUpdateStudent
4. http://..../GetStudent

I have changed the route names as "CreateOrUpdate" and "Get". and deployed the changes again.It is giving as NotFound status.

If I delete service from fabric and deploy the changes, the endpoints are giving the response.

Do you guys have any idea why the routing changes are not updated?

Comment: In what way did you deployed the app when it didn't reflect the changes?
What upgrade properties are specified in publish profile?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have two routes the same. This can be a cause for your application to have routing conflicts. You can see this in logs if you're using azure and it's more simple.